# storm cluster mode, distributed bolt/worker load sharing

Tags: apache-storm

HI: I will have a large capacity storm analysis task. For me, I want to spin off many bolt/workers across different nodes/machines to take the task so that every machine could share the load . I am wondering how to write bolt/workers/topology so that they could communicate with each other. In the below codes, I submit topology in one machine, how to write bolt/worker/config in other machines so that topology is aware of other machines' bolt/worker. I suppose I could not submit topology in one machine and submit same topology in other machines.
Any hints on storm worker load sharing?

```java
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import storm.kafka.KafkaSpout;
import storm.kafka.SpoutConfig;
import storm.kafka.StringScheme;
import storm.kafka.ZkHosts;
import backtype.storm.Config;
import backtype.storm.StormSubmitter;
import backtype.storm.generated.AlreadyAliveException;
import backtype.storm.generated.InvalidTopologyException;
import backtype.storm.spout.SchemeAsMultiScheme;
import backtype.storm.task.OutputCollector;
import backtype.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import backtype.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
import backtype.storm.topology.base.BaseRichBolt;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Tuple;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Values;

public class StormClusterMain {
    private static final String SPOUTNAME="KafkaSpout"; 
    private static final String ANALYSISBOLT = "ClusterAnalysisWorker";
    private static final String CLIENTID = "ClusterStorm";
    private static final String TOPOLOGYNAME = "ClusterTopology";

    private static class AppAnalysisBolt extends BaseRichBolt {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -6885792881303198646L;
        private static final String collectionName="clusterusers";
        private OutputCollector _collector;
        private AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0); 
        private static final Logger boltLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppAnalysisBolt.class); 

        public void prepare(Map conf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
            _collector = collector;
        }

        public void execute(Tuple tuple) {  
            boltLogger.error("Message received:"+tuple.getString(0));
            _collector.emit(tuple, new Values(tuple.getString(0) + "!!!"));
            _collector.ack(tuple);
        }

        public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
            declarer.declare(new Fields("word"));
        }


    }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws AlreadyAliveException, InvalidTopologyException{

       String zookeepers = null;
       String topicName = null;
       if(args.length == 2 ){
           zookeepers = args[0];
           topicName = args[1];
       }else{
           System.out.println("You need to have two arguments: kafka zookeeper:port and topic name");
           System.out.println("Usage :.xxx");
           System.exit(-1);
       }        

       SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(new ZkHosts(zookeepers),
            topicName,
            "",// zookeeper root path for offset storing
            CLIENTID);
       spoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
       KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig);

       TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
       builder.setSpout(SPOUTNAME, kafkaSpout, 1);
       builder.setBolt(ANALYSISBOLT, new AppAnalysisBolt())
                                                 .shuffleGrouping(SPOUTNAME);

        //Configuration
        Config conf = new Config();
        conf.setDebug(false);
        //Topology run
        conf.setNumWorkers(3);
        StormSubmitter.submitTopologyWithProgressBar(TOPOLOGYNAME, conf, builder.createTopology());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've already done it, unless something has gone wrong.

When you submit a topology to Storm, the Nimbus service looks at the load on the cluster via the Supervisor processes spread throughout the cluster. Nimbus then provides some quantity of resources for the topology to run. Those resources are oftentimes spread throughout the various Supervisor nodes in the cluster, and they will process tuples in parallel. Nimbus occasionally revisits these decisions and changes which nodes process what in an attempt to keep load in the cluster balanced. As a user you should never notice that process.

Assuming your Storm cluster is setup properly, the only thing you have to do to is submit the topology. Storm takes care of the whole multi-node parallel processing thing for you.

That said, the AtomicInteger you have in there is going to act pretty weird, as storm slices up your code across multiple servers, and even multiple JVMs on a single host. If you want to solve for a case where individual storm processes need to know about state of the larger cluster, you will be best served externalizing that to some sort of independent datastore (ie redis or hbase).

Comment: It is clear answer. I just explain in my own way here. It is supervisor nodes takes the load. Say builder.setBolt(ANALYSISBOLT, new AppAnalysisBolt(),10). shuffleGrouping(SPOUTNAME), Does that mean I need to allocate/add/assign enough supervisor to the cluster so that 10 workers/bolters have enough resources(memory,cpu) to consume tuples in parallel.  Am I right?

Comment: No, not really :)

That integer parameter, aka parallelism_hint, specifies the number of executors. Any given worker process supports running multiple executor threads. So baring any other configuration, you'll spawn 10 executor threads per worker process running the topology. 

For more information on this: [how to tune the parallelism hint in storm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371073/how-to-tune-the-parallelism-hint-in-storm)

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer. Now I understand executor threads and worker processes. My current question is how to increase capacity of cluster. Which node I shall add? Nimbus, supervisor, worker process? If I have one machine for Nimbus, one machhine for supervisor, one machine to submit topology and workers, if capacity is running out, what shall I do? adding more workers is reasonable idea. But then how to add worker machine? How to write worker/bolt codes so that they know the topology and let storm find added work/bolt machine?Of course in topology, I will increase number of workers.

Comment: If you have a functioning Storm cluster, in order to increase capacity you add a Supervisor node to the cluster. That's it. Storm takes care of the rest.....I'll revise my answer with more information on exactly how that works in a bit.