# Apache Storm Issues with bolts on the same worker

Tags: multithreading, apache-storm

I have a question around Apache Storm and how multi-threading works.

We have 2 bolts that are transferring data to each others: Prediction Bolt to FragmentFilter bolt
Both bolts are on the same worker using port 6705 as you can see in the picture here:
[worker_description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXSTr.png)

When I open the log, I notice that the prediction bolt stops working to let the FragmentFilter bolt do his job, they are not running in parralel based on the logs and information below:

> 2021-10-01 15:26:12.492 o.a.s.t.ShellBolt Thread-20 [INFO] ShellLog pid:28655, name:predictions start process
> 2021-10-01 15:26:12.492 o.a.s.t.ShellBolt Thread-20 [INFO] ShellLog pid:28655, name:predictions end process
> 2021-10-01 15:26:12.492 o.a.s.t.ShellBolt Thread-20 [INFO] ShellLog pid:28655, name:predictions start process
> 2021-10-01 15:26:12.492 o.a.s.t.ShellBolt Thread-20 [INFO] ShellLog pid:28655, name:predictions end process
> 2021-10-01 15:26:12.492 o.a.s.t.ShellBolt Thread-20 [INFO] ShellLog pid:28655, name:predictions start process
> 2021-10-01 15:26:12.493 o.a.s.t.ShellBolt Thread-20 [INFO] ShellLog pid:28655, name:predictions end process
> 2021-10-01 15:26:12.545 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [227aea40-2e7e-421c-91b3-da8259b8bd15, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:12.635 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [7255c225-a8c5-41bc-8b4e-7f640063a0ee, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:12.643 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [66665829-f708-4f2e-8e5d-ee8866d91662, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:12.857 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [e2b8bde1-747a-4546-8e19-30c7623ab0a1, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:12.974 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [17278f27-ae05-4bb0-a20c-9ca6a0ccdab1, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:13.156 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [24715630-93c4-40bd-9086-0671c486e692, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:13.180 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [501ca1e5-c2ed-45b0-ae90-313f4103548c, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:13.611 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [c575e479-53c5-47cd-b3bb-521e75c83028, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:13.844 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [e5d6ee4d-6202-43f9-a9ef-17d9be5b02f7, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:13.916 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [4b04c06c-b92d-439c-b5ed-64bb52b1d7fc, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:14.091 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [28c9a824-fedf-4478-8d2d-fade0289438e, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:14.435 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [675a05f0-7f88-4f65-a26e-6f25723db0ae, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:14.781 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [1547c67f-6e37-4f24-aabc-cedd11a050ff, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:14.816 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [d037c364-35c8-4364-b305-403d48fb0f77, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:14.816 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [369b8eee-f8ac-43bf-af81-f087f6de62f6, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:15.095 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [9a85a64f-0261-41bc-9672-27d039cbab5c, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:15.234 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [4d306b23-06a6-42b0-88e2-28ba9deaaad9, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:15.260 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [9b6aaa36-2223-4f1b-9653-1e60ede94f8b, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:15.285 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [76d3dbb4-1546-45ad-993b-5fa3efad8087, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:15.399 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [d9644f1a-85e0-46e1-bbfd-faa85cd145b7, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:15.479 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [894a12fb-7b06-4c1c-9976-386b0100fd71, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:15.693 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [6bad7162-d811-4712-8049-3ed2c5b69f29, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:15.697 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [8dfb1d95-c869-4b1f-b660-9d4cc7320a30, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:15.711 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [1c102b77-da2b-4af9-bb11-bfc04dedad24, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:15.728 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [f66c2bc0-ba67-45a7-9c41-cd64b7ae70d5, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:15.855 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [ca2679b1-13d0-405b-ab76-9ff89cfc3729, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:15.975 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [75b20990-12b7-4d88-a2e1-23541e5b1b78, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:15.991 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [bf7c2551-3a63-46bd-906e-e403a4a6a26b, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:16.095 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [b360b50a-1a31-4e05-ac23-a798740d8d55, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:16.168 STDIO Thread-11-FragmentFilter-executor[4 4] [INFO] Emitted values: [033862c7-ac16-49ef-bb82-eb1c87739508, ]
> 2021-10-01 15:26:16.257 o.a.s.t.ShellBolt Thread-20 [INFO] ShellLog pid:28655, name:predictions start process
> 2021-10-01 15:26:16.257 o.a.s.t.ShellBolt Thread-20 [INFO] ShellLog pid:28655, name:predictions start add_row
> 2021-10-01 15:26:16.333 o.a.s.t.ShellBolt Thread-20 [INFO] ShellLog pid:28655, name:predictions end add_row
> 2021-10-01 15:26:16.333 o.a.s.t.ShellBolt Thread-20 [INFO] ShellLog pid:28655, name:predictions end process
> 2021-10-01 15:26:16.334 o.a.s.t.ShellBolt Thread-20 [INFO] ShellLog pid:28655, name:predictions start process
> 2021-10-01 15:26:16.334 o.a.s.t.ShellBolt Thread-20 [INFO] ShellLog pid:28655, name:predictions start update
> 2021-10-01 15:26:16.337 o.a.s.t.ShellBolt Thread-20 [INFO] ShellLog pid:28655, name:predictions end update
> 2021-10-01 15:26:16.337 o.a.s.t.ShellBolt Thread-20 [INFO] ShellLog pid:28655, name:predictions end process
> 2021-10-01 15:26:16.337 o.a.s.t.ShellBolt Thread-20 [INFO] ShellLog pid:28655, name:predictions start process

Thread-20 for the prediction bolt seems to be stopping at 2021-10-01 15:26:12.493 to let the thread-11 (FragmentFilter Bolt) process information then Bolt prediction restarts working at 2021-10-01 15:26:16.257 loosing 4 seconds in the process. This is creating a huge latency problem for us.

Is that normal ? how can we solve it ?

Comment: This responds to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371073/how-to-tune-the-parallelism-hint-in-storm
One key thing to note that if you intent to run more than one tasks per executor it does not increase the level of parallelism. Because executor uses one single thread to process all the tasks i.e tasks run serially on an executor.

Comment: I am wondering how/if there are really interactions between those threads, since each bolt is serialized and distributed separately, right?